# Laravel 5 Unable to detect application namespace

Tags: laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel 5 and trying to understand it bit by bit and at the moment I'm really confused with error messages. MVC is new thing to me.

What I'm trying to do is blog system for my site and I've downloaded package called "Serverfireteam/blog"; https://phppackages.org/p/serverfireteam/blog

It installed just fine, I guess. When I go to http://myhost.com/public/panel/login I get the login screen but when I login it gives me this error:

> ErrorException in Application.php line 1119: Unable to detect application namespace. (View: /var/www/html/mpa2/resources/views/vendor/panelViews/dashboard.blade.php)

&&

> RuntimeException in Application.php line 1119: Unable to detect application namespace.

Funny thing is it worked before just fine, I could login and make/edit blog posts and I could see them go to mysql-database. Also I was able to see them on site. Then I started to modify view/template files for integrating blog output to my site's own layout.

I've got no idea what gives, I've tried to google for solution but no help. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Okay, I solved it. What I did to solve this:

```
composer update
```

gave me following error:

```
[Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]

"./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
 Parse error on line 9:
"require-dev
 ---------------------^
 Expected: 'STRING' - It appears you have an extra trailing comma
```

I opened `composer.json` and there was one extra comma in last line:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
}
```

**Removed** the comma so it looked like this:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*"
}
```

And problem was gone.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, and more importantly, posting the solution you found. It was my problem as well, and now others can quickly resolve this.

Comment: Thanks. I was having the same problem and I solved it with your solution.

Comment: Was having almost the same problem, it was a merge conflict in the `composer.json` file. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I think this could have happened while pushing/merging your branchces to git repo

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem, your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 25):

Usually, this means that your composer.json file contains invalid JSON. Usually an extra comma at the end of an array.

Try running this to tell you exactly where the issue is:

```
composer diagnose
```

Comment: Saved my day!. Most people don't know this.

Comment: In my case, you were right (it was an extra comma at the end of the array in composer.json)

Answer (score 11):

laravel version: 5.8.3

**[One more Reason]: default app path in composer.json is modified**

the default setup looks like this

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/"
 },
```

If its modified to say,

```
"psr-4": {
    "Core\\": "app/Core/"
 },
```

the `make` commands with artisan wont work, and a few other things

the reason is https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L296

**app** is static in the path, and here is the where the exception is thrown https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L1143

This default behavior can be modified in `bootstrap/app.php`

Here is my solution [reference: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-i-can-change-laravel-directory-structure?page=1]

## Solution:

`Core/Application.php`

```
<?php

namespace Core;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application as IlluminateApplication;

class Application extends IlluminateApplication
{
    protected $appPath = __DIR__;
}
```

`bootstap/app.php`

```
$app = new \Core\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);
```

Comment: I had similar issue in my composer, I added a helper file inside App folder that I have referenced inside composer and I used single quotes that did it. I had to use double and do dump-auto load and update now it works fine

Comment: A solution for Laravel 10: in `bootstrap/app.php`, add `$app->useAppPath($app->basePath('Core));` (of course, change "Core" to your application folder).

Answer (score 3):

Please Write this Command on the project root
**composer diagnose**
This Command Will detect the problem
my case I found this

```
 [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
  "./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
  Parse error on line 1:
  3:06 PM 08-Dec-20{
  ^
  Expected one of: 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

Then I removed

> 3:06 PM 08-Dec-20

Then I have Created Controller Succesfully.
I Hope The composer diagnose Command Will Detect Your Problem.

Answer (score 1):

What caused this for me was having lines commented with //. The // can be on its own line or at the end of the line. Also having comma at the end can cause this.

Removing the comments solved this. And/or removing the extra ending comma.

The error happens for "composer update", and artisan commands such as "php artisan make:controller TestsController --resource", or "php artisan make:model Test"

Answer (score 1):

you could open composer.json with visual code.
and
it will parse and mark the issue

i have solve this issue like that